# Не работает шаблонизация на хостинге

Tags: javascript, express

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

async function pageLoad(id) {
  let url = `тут была ссылка с токеном &id=${id}`;
  let response = await fetch(url);
  let commits = await response.json();
  let ctx = commits.results[0]
  return ctx;
}

router.get('/', function (req, res) {
  ctx = pageLoad(req.query.id);
  ctx.then((result) => {
    if (result.material_data.episodes_total == 0) {
      result.material_data.episodes_total = '?'
    };

    res.render('anipage', {
      title: result.title,
      epA: result.material_data.episodes_aired,
      epT: result.material_data.episodes_total,
      Duration: result.material_data.duration,
      origName: result.title_orig,
      Type: result.material_data.anime_kind,
      Studios: result.material_data.anime_studios.join(', '),
      Genre: result.material_data.anime_genres.join(', '),
      Year: result.year,
      Description: result.material_data.anime_description,
      poster: result.material_data.poster_url,
      sceen1: result.screenshots[0],
      sceen2: result.screenshots[1],
      iframe: result.link
    });
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

При использовании этого кода на локальном хосте все работает прекрасно, но при попытке запустить код на хостинге, как только отправляю запрос на эту страницу, сайт ложится с ошибкой 504

Comment: пропишите catch

Comment: Вполне возможно что этот участок кода имеет дело с разными данными...